# Appoximation of Multiplicity

Tags: logarithms, approximation, entropy

I am having trouble between two steps of a physics formula for multiplicity.

Currently I have:
$$
N\ln(N) - (N-q)\ln(N-q)
$$
I am solid on how to get here, but the next steps are what follows:

$$
\text{Assume } N\gg q\gg 1 \text{, and use } [ \ln(1+x)\approx x] \text{ when } x \gg 1,\\
N\ln(N)-(N-q)\left(\ln N-\frac{q}{N} \right),\\
\approx q\ln N.
$$

I have been staring at these lines for a few hours now. I cannot figure out how to go from the first formula to the last formula. Any help is much appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First $\ln(1+x)\approx x$ when $x\color{red}{\ll}1$, not the contrary.

The last formula is obtained factoring$N$ in the last log, and using propertes thereof:
\begin{align}
N\ln N  - (N-q)\ln(N-q)&=N\ln(N) - (N-q)\ln N\Bigl(1-\frac qN\Bigr)\\
&=\not N\not{\ln\not N }- (\not N-q)\ln N - (N-q)\ln\Bigl(1-\frac qN\Bigr)\\
&\approx q\ln N-(N-q)\Bigl(-\frac qN\Bigr)= q\ln N -q+\frac{q^2}N\\
&\approx q\ln N\qquad\text{since }\;q\ll 1\;\text{ and }\;\frac qN\ll 1.
\end{align}